# paperclipで画像を保存する際に最適化する方法

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

現在、Railsでwebサービスの開発を行っているのですが、画像を多く利用しているため、パフォーマンスがあまりよくありません。そのため、画像を最適化しファイルサイズを下げようと考えています。

基本的な手順は以下を想定しています。

1. fromから画像をpostしてもらう
2. コントローラまたはモデルで画像を最適化
3. paperclipでDBに保存

上記のようにpaperclipでDBに保存する際に、最適化処理を通してから保存したいと考えています。

実際にpaperclipと組み合わせて最適化を行っている方、その他の手段で最適化を行っている方など、いたら教えていただきたいです。また、もっと良い方法で画像を最適化できる方法などあればそちらでも構いません。

その際、おすすめのパッケージ,gemなどあれば教えていただければと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paperclip でアップロード時に簡単に画像を最適化するのであれば、以下の gem が使えるかと思います。

https://github.com/janfoeh/paperclip-optimizer

また、paperclip 単体でも、リサイズ時の `ImageMagick` のオプションを指定出来ますので、そちらを利用する方法もあります。

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation#optimizing-thumbnails-for-the-web

Comment: 素早い対応ありがとうござます！
早速試してみたいと思います。

Comment: @chanyama さん、その後いかがでしたか？もしうまくいったのであれば、解決済みマーク(緑のチェックマーク)を付けておいてくださいね。